# SQL - How to return Boolean value if values exists in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of values (parcels) I need to check against the database to make sure they all exist already. Sometimes there are 100's of these parcels. I want to return basically a true or false value so I can find out which one doesn't exist and address that particular parcel. The date aspect is I need to filter by always the prior year. I'm pretty green with SQL so I appreciate the help.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Property WHERE taxyear = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 and (parcel in 
('1719309002000',
 '1024247013000',
 '1024247008000',
 '1024247001000'))
 THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS ExistsStatus
 FROM Property
```

and

```
SELECT Parcel, Powner, taxyear, 
CASE WHEN taxyear = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 and (parcel in 
('1719309002000',
 '1024247013000',
 '1024247008000',
 '1024247001000'
)) 
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS result_field
FROM Property;
```

which just goes through every parcel in the table putting 0 or 1 and I only want results for the values I give it.

Comment: Put `parcel in 
('1719309002000',
 '1024247013000',
 '1024247008000',
 '1024247001000'
)` in the `Where` clause to filter just what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `exists` with a table of values.  This will prevent duplicates in the result set:

```
SELECT v.parcel,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM Property p
                          WHERE p.taxyear = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 AND
                                p.parcel = v.parcel
                         ) 
             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END) AS ExistsStatus
FROM (VALUES ('1719309002000'),
             ('1024247013000'),
             ('1024247008000'),
             ('1024247001000')
     ) v(parcel)
```

Comment: Thank you! And thanks to everyone. A few of these queries worked well. This one allows for the easiest copying and pasting from an excel sheet with a hundred parcels. Can't thank you all enough! Great ideas and I learned quite a bit from this.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to create a derived table containing the input data you are checking for, because just limiting your results to the ID's you are searching for will never be able to give you a false return. There will not be a row for a value that doesn't match.

By doing this, you are starting with a table that contains all of the parcel numbers you are looking for, and then LEFT JOINing the real data so that you don't lose any rows on the join. Finally, the CASE statement checks if the join managed to connect an existing row.

You will notice this derived table is being created by a series of UNION statements - essentially sticking rows together repeatedly to create an in-memory table. You can do this differently by actually creating a "temporary table", but I have found that in the absence of any intermediate processing, this method is slightly faster.

```
SELECT InputTable.parcel, (CASE WHEN Property.parcel IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END) AS ExistsStatus
FROM (
  SELECT '1719309002000' AS parcel UNION
  SELECT '1024247013000' UNION
  SELECT '1024247008000' UNION
  SELECT '1024247001000'
) AS InputTable
LEFT JOIN Property ON Property.parcel = InputTable.parcel AND Property.taxyear = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I like to see, and leave, answers that give the OP a little context around why they work.  +1 Just a note, though, that Gordon's `FROM VALUES` clause is lighter weight, both in terms of typing and processing, than a `UNION` list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll read up on that syntax. I also just noticed that I left out the tax year condition.
I believe it should work fine if you change the last line to
 
`LEFT JOIN Property ON Property.parcel = InputTable.parcel AND Property.taxyear = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1`

Comment: there's an `edit` option right under your answer. If you click on that, it'll open the editor back up and you can add your amendment to your answer.

Comment: Done. Was just unsure if it was poor form to edit an answer someone has already upvoted/supported. Thanks again!

Comment: this is a decent answer, but this isn't a temporary table.  A temporary table gets materialized in the tempdb and can be used in multiple statements in the same connection or until dropped.  This is a derived table.  A Common Table Expression would be another good way of doing this and logically separating the steps. Also just to point it out this could technically contain duplicates if ParcelNumber isn't unique in property table though I doubt that is an issue

Comment: Yeah I wasn't actually sure what the correct term for this is. It does create an in-memory table that only lasts temporarily/during the query, but the name "temporary table" is a bit of a loaded term with other expectations.   *Edited my answer to fix terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Put your values to check into a temporary table and then left outer join with the Property table.  Something like this...

```
Create Table #MyParcels( ParcelNumber bigint);
INSERT #MyParcles VALUES ('1234567890'), ('2345678901'), ....

SELECT ParcelNumber, CASE WHEN parcel is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as [Exists] FROM #MyParcels LEFT OUTER JOIN Property ON ParcelNumber = parcel
```

This will return 1 row for every record in #MyParcels with a 0/1 indicating whether or not it exists in Property.

Comment: this is a good answer, except need to account for the year filter in the original question. Also it is actually possible that it could return multiple Rows with 1 for exists if Property could have multiple records per ParcelNumber.  I would doubt that given the context but it depends on constrains/keys

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `UNION` operation. Like the following query:

```
SELECT Parcel, MAX(result_field) AS result_field
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Parcel,
    1 AS result_field -- exists in Property table, so value is 1
  FROM Property
  WHERE TaxYear = YEAR(GETDATE() -1)

  UNION

  -- create a temporary table with your given Parcels
  SELECT 
    Parcel,
    0 AS result_field -- doesn't exist in Property table, So it's 0
  FROM (
   VALUES
     ('1719309002000'),
     ('1024247013000'),
     ('1024247008000'),
     ('1024247001000')
   ) AS T (Parcel)

) AS ResultTable
GROUP By Parcel
```

Here is the working [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93079b8c93233659aaf33f5f65e0e65c).

Hope this helps. Thanks!